# Java + Selenium: How to know if WebElement is clickable in a way other than isDisplayed, isEnabled and findElement?

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, exception

I am aware that how generally it is tested that WebElement is clickable:

The test it in something like this:

```
public static boolean isElementFoundDisplayedEnabled(WebDriver driver, String accessor){

        return driver.findElements(By.xpath(accessor)).size() > 0 && driver.findElement(By.xpath(accessor)).isDisplayed() && driver.findElement(By.xpath(accessor)).isEnabled();
        //isDisplayed(): method avoids the problem of having to parse an element's "style" attribute to check hidden/visible. False when element is not present
        //isEnabled(): generally return true for everything but disabled input elements.
    }
```

This function has flaw, that it checks only if Element is clickable at DOM level, but if because of some css mess-up, the element is hidden/overlapped, one can get Exception as:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not
>   clickable at point (781, 704). Other element would receive the click:
>
> ...

In such situations, one can still click the element using:

```
// Assume driver is a valid WebDriver instance that
// has been properly instantiated elsewhere.
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

But, I am interested in knowing that, how we can check without clicking through `executor.executeScript` that, that WebElement is not hidden/overlapped by other element and is PERFECTLY clickable.

Can someone please shed somelight, I have done few hours of research on these and reached nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of creating a function that handles all clicks, etc. like this but if I were forced to write one, it would look something like this. Comments inside explain what's going on.

```
public static void clickElement(By locator) throws InterruptedException
{
    try
    {
        // first we try the standard wait for element to be clickable and click it
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        // element never becomes present
    }
    catch (WebDriverException e)
    {
        // click is blocked by another element, retry for 10 seconds
        while (true)
        {
            Instant timeOut = Instant.now().plusSeconds(10);
            try
            {
                driver.findElement(locator).click();
                break;
            }
            catch (WebDriverException e2)
            {
                // ignore additional blocked click exceptions
            }

            if (Instant.now().isAfter(timeOut))
            {
                // element is still blocked after retries for 10 seconds, fallback to JSE click
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(locator));
            }

            // slight pause between loops
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Some feedback on your function...
You should pass around `By` instances instead of strings, e.g.

```
By locator = By.id("myId");
```

That way your functions can be more flexible and aren't hard coded to XPath only. Also you are scraping the page 3 times with your function. Scrape the page once, and then use the stored element to do your checks for visible and enabled, e.g.

```
public static boolean isElementFoundDisplayedEnabled(WebDriver driver, By locator)
{
    List<WebElement> e = driver.findElements(locator);

    return !e.isEmpty() && e.get(0).isDisplayed() && e.get(0).isEnabled();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some facts and insights to your question:

1. I feel the method `isElementFoundDisplayedEnabled(WebDriver driver, String accessor)` is a overhead when Selenium already have the in-built `WebDriverWait` class at your disposal. I will come back about `WebDriverWait` in the later part of my answer.
2. Documentation clearly mentions [**`isDisplayed()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed--) checks only if this element displayed or not. This method avoids the problem of having to parse an element's "style" attribute.
3. Documentation mentions [**`isEnabled()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isEnabled--) checks only if the element currently enabled or not. This will generally return true for everything but disabled input elements.
4. So the function `isElementFoundDisplayedEnabled(WebDriver driver, String accessor)` is necessaryly not covering if the `WebElement` is `clickable` or not. Hence there may be some cases where you may face `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (781, 704). Other element would receive the click`.
5. Now, when you see `Element is not clickable at point (781, 704)` you already mentioned about **`JavascriptExecutor`** click and that works.
6. So to check that if an element is clickable or not we can simply take help of `WebDriverWait` class with **`ExpectedConditions`** set to **`elementToBeClickable`**.
7. An example will be:

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   WebElement ele = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("element_id")));
   ```
8. Documentation clearly mentions  [**`Element is Clickable - it is Displayed and Enabled`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)
9. A closer look at the [**`elementToBeClickable()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) method clearly mentions that it returns **`the (same) WebElement once it is clickable (visible and enabled)`**

Hence the solution for your question is **`WebDriverWait`** i.e. **`ExplicitWait`**

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that even once an element is found to be clickable, either by OP's function or `ExplicitWait`, it can still run into the `Element is not clickable at point X` error. The question is how to handle this situation, including the not clickable error.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to note which attribute has the property of hidden or visible and based on that you can write something like this.

Example:

```
 <input id ="email" style="margin-top: 0px; visibility: visible;" >
```

Code:

```
public Boolean isVisibleAndClickable(WebElement email, WebDriver driver ){

            Boolean flag = false;
    try{
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(email));

            if(email.isDisplayed()){
            String style = email.getAttribute("style");
            if(style.contains("hidden")){
            System.out.println("Element is hidden");
            }
            else if(style.contains("visible")){
               System.out.println("Element is visible and clickable");
               flag = true;
           }else{
               System.out.println("Element is not displayed");
           }
           }
       } catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Exception occured waiting for the element"+e.getMessage());
     }

            return flag;
     }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Comment: I have modified my method to verify clickable functionality which should now address the question of verifying without actually clicking the Web element.

Comment: @JeffC I also believe by his question his requirement was not to click on the element prior verifying whether the element is clickable or not. I see you have clicked the element straight away in your answer.

Comment: After you checked if the element is displayed, why are you checking for hidden style? If it's displayed, it's not going to have a hidden style... that's what `.isDisplayed()` is for. Also, just because an element is visible doesn't mean it's clickable. It could be covered by another element, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the xpath contains function, the logic operators and the ancestor option. For example:

.//a[@behavior.id='myid']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'typeClass')]/.//span

This line find the children 'span' from the 'div'(@class filter), and for find this div I started finding the 'a' with behavior.id

And for the visibility I always use the Wait or FluentWait options:

```
public static WebElement xpathVisible(String xpath) {
    return new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(IMPLICIT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(RETRY_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class).until(ExpectedConditions
                    .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));
}
```

And maybe it is useful use some capability over the driver as elementScrollBehavior to search the elements from the bottom:

```
capabilities.setCapability("elementScrollBehavior", 1); // 0- from Top,
                                                            // 1 - from
                                                            // bottom
```

Something I used once was:

1. Obtain a near webelement.
2. Send a short cut as Keys.TAB or Keys.SHIFT+Keys.TAB.
3. Take any property from the element to check you are on the correct button.
4. Send a Keys.Enter.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Comment: It is my way to know if a WebElement is Visible, with the FluentWait and the visibilityOfElementLocated method

Comment: Now with ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable

Comment: The issue is how to handle an element that is clickable but is covered by another element. Waiting for it to be clickable doesn't solve that issue. Selenium will attempt the click and fail because it ends up clicking another element.